# Default Port required on MySQL Connection

Tags: php, mysql

I installed MySQL on my OS X Mountain Lion box and got it to work. Now, I'm having problems getting a new WordPress site to access it and it has been suggested that my server is not configured correctly because I have to supply the port. I created this test code to verify the connection:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', 'somepassword', 'gazos');

if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
else
    echo 'Good connection to gazos';
?>
```

It returns a good connection. It errors out if I remove the port. I have something similar in another non-WordPress website that works fine. I don't remember configuring MySQL. I just installed it. When I checked my my.cnf file, everything is commented out except:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Is it normal to supply the default port on a connection? If not, what do I need to fix.

Comment: Maybe try 'new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'somepassword', 'gazos');`

Comment: And no you shouldn't need the port number on there http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: Check your php.ini for port override http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-port

Comment: @Banning: 127.0.0.1 without the port works and fixes the WordPress issue. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'somepassword', 'gazos');`